# ZeroMQ with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm trying to just do this line and use browserify on it:

```
var zmq = require ('zmq');
```

It outputs an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function
```

I can't seem to find anything that talks about ZeroMQ and Browserify, and the only error that's similar is where the word 'exists' is replaced with 'undefined'. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What ZeroMQ library are you using?

Comment: Bindings for node.js, version 2.11.0

Answer (score 2):

`zeromq.node` is meant for use on the server side with Nodejs.  It is just a thin Javascript wrapper around the ZeroMQ library, and in fact has a [binary module](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/binding.cc).  As such, it is not meant for use in the browser (eg with Browserify).